# Need help finishing or rewriting this algorithm for navigating a Generic Collection

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq

I am trying to come up with the code for an algorithm to set the current object based on whether or not the user clicks a "forward" button or a "backward" button.

```
public Step CurrentStep
{
    get { return _currentStep; }
    set
    {
        if (_currentStep != value)
        {
            _currentStep = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentStep");
        }
    }
}

private int CurrentStepIndex { get; set; }

private void NextStep()
{
    CurrentStepIndex++;
    GotoStep();
}

private void PreviousStep()
{
    CurrentStepIndex--;
    GotoStep();
}

private void GotoStep()
{
    var query = from step in CurrentPhase.Steps
                where ????
                select step;

    CurrentStep = query.First();
}
```

`CurrentPhase.Steps` is an `ObservableCollection<Step> Steps {get; set;}`. And in the constructor for this class I have a means of setting a default value for the property "`CurrentStep`" so there will always be one to spring-board off of.

Given this collection I was hoping to use the index of the `CurrentStep` object stored in `CurrentStepIndex` to go find where this item is in the collection and then change that index by decrementing it or incrementing it. Then, using some sort of linq query, go find the "next step" at the new index.

Unfortunately I am having a hard time formulating my LINQ query. What's more, I am not sure if this algorithm is going to work.

What do I need to complete my LINQ query so that this algorithm works?

Or, is there a better way of achieving what I want?

Comment: 1) You probably don't want to be using LINQ here.  LINQ is built around a one way iterator, not a backwards iterator.  You'll be fighting it the whole way trying to get that.  Better to start from the ground level.  2) What are you trying to create a two way iterator for?  Without knowing what the underlying collection is, we really can't help you.

Comment: @Servy The underlying collection is an ObservableCollection<T>.

Comment: Use index to access . It is the fastest way of getting a data from collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to use LINQ here. [ObservableCollection<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) inherits from [Collection<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132434.aspx) which has [Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132434.aspx) property (indexer in C#). This meanse that you can use following code instead of LINQ:

```
private void GotoStep()
{
    CurrentStep = CurrentPhase.Steps[CurrentStepIndex];
}
```

Comment: This definitely looks plausible. However, I just realized I dont have the index of the CurrentStep when I set it for the first time in my constructor. How can I get that index?

Comment: @IsaiahNelson I suppose you need to find index of the CurrentStep in costructor using loop or `First()` extension method.

Answer (score 1):

use the following but make sure to control overflow

```
  if(CurrentStepIndex>=0 && CurrentStepIndex<CurrentPhase.Steps.Count)
  {
   CurrentStep= CurrentPhase.Steps[CurrentStepIndex)
  }
```

Comment: This would be ungodly inefficient.  Please don't do this.

Comment: Accessing by index the most fast way you can do. It is BigO(1)

Comment: @DanHunex How would I handle control over flow in this instance?